# Why are my testing-library queries not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am using Jest/React Testing Library(RTL) to to unit testing for the UI.

None of my RTL queries work.

It keeps telling me errors like

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="analysis-categories-header"]
```

no matter how I query it.

I have tried `getBy*, findBy*(yes, with async...await), getByTestId` and everything.

The only difference is that when I use `findBy*` I get an extra error that says

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

even `screen.debug()` is ignored and not working.

Out of the 13 tests I have, only one test work surprisingly. The queries go through.
test:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Login from '../src/pages/login';

test('renders logo and login box with "LOG IN" text and two buttons', () => {
  const initState = {};
  const mockStore = configureStore();

  render(
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Provider store={mockStore(initState)}>
        <Login />
      </Provider>
    </HelmetProvider>,
  );

  expect(screen.getByTestId('login-logo')).toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.getByTestId('login-title')).toBeVisible();
  expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' })).toBeVisible();
  expect(
    screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In With Intuit' }),
  ).toBeVisible();
});
```

component:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Container,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import Logo from 'src/components/Logo';
import axios from 'src/lib/axios';
import gtm from 'src/lib/gtm';

const Login: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    gtm.push({ event: 'page_view' });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && isAuthenticated) {
      router.push('/recommendations');
    }
  }, [isLoading, isAuthenticated]);

  const handleIntuitLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/auth/sign-in-with-intuit');
      window.location = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  };

  const handleAuth0Login = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/auth/sign-in-with-auth0');
      window.location = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Login</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          minHeight: '100vh',
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="sm" sx={{ py: '80px' }}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              mb: 8,
            }}
          >
            <Link href="/login">
              <Box>
                <Logo height={100} width={300} />
              </Box>
            </Link>
          </Box>
          <Card>
            <CardContent
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                p: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Box
                sx={{
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  mb: 3,
                }}
              >
                <div>
                  <Typography
                    color="textPrimary"
                    gutterBottom
                    variant="h4"
                    data-testid="login-title"
                  >
                    Log in
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              </Box>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  mt: 3,
                }}
              >
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleAuth0Login}
                  fullWidth
                  size="large"
                  type="button"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Sign In
                </Button>
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleIntuitLogin}
                  fullWidth
                  size="large"
                  type="button"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Sign In With Intuit
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

The only difference is that this component (nextjs page) does not use redux thunk. This is how far I got to find the cause.

Comment: Do the components you're using actually do anything with that prop? What actually gets rendered?

Comment: @jonrsharpe hello, I have figured out that it is because of RequireScope component, which will only allow rendering of children components if user is authenticated. Please see and advise here! Would greatly appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702633/why-is-none-of-my-react-testing-library-queries-working